# In dataform, how to have my javascript code log information?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, dataform

I'm trying to write a Dataform workflow able to read some complex data from a GitHub repository and transform it into a SQL table.
Since code is quite complex, I want to write some logs (typically using `console.log`). But as far as in understand, those logs are never visible in Google Cloud Logging. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to BenBirt on [Dataform GitHub discussions](https://github.com/dataform-co/dataform/discussions/1543#discussioncomment-7055476)

> Console output is indeed not available.
>
> However, just to avoid confusion: Dataform JS code is not executed at workflow execution time - it is executed at compile time, i.e. turning the JS into pure SQL (which can then be executed at some later date). So it's not as though you could e.g. have a console.log outputting some text as a result of running some SQL.